# Web API interface theory

Tags: magento2, webapi

I am writing a frontend that lists some custom data. It calls an `endpoint /rest/v1/custom/get` that hooks into my `CustomListInterface` defined in the webapi.xml, this then returns a list of records in a custom database.

```
+-------------+----------+-------------+
|  entity_id  |   title  |    order_id |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
|       1     |   Test   |       2     |
+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

So when I call the endpoint, it outputs the json to represent the data structure of the table.

```
{
    entity_id: 1, 
    title : "Test",
    order_id : 2
}
```

What I want is for the result to JOIN the order table and return a more complex structure such as.

```
    {
    entity_id: 1, 
    title : "Test",
    order_id : 2,
    order : {
         entity_id : 2,
         base_total: 125.0000,
         qty : 4,
         increment_id : "M8036863"
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest some examples in the codebase of how best to implement this.